# Python 3: Can't properly encode and print a downloaded string with /xXX literals

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, beautifulsoup

So here's the problem. I want to, for example, download and print a list of all possible languages from

```
https://www.fanfiction.net/game/Pok%C3%A9mon/
```

(Visible under 'filters' button).

In HTML, it's represented as a following series of options:

```
<option value='17' >Svenska<option value='31' >čeština<option value='10' >Русский
<option value='39' >देवनागरी<option value='38' >ภาษาไทย<option value='5' >中文<option value='6' >日本語
```

I download it using urllib.request package

```
def getByUrl(self,url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()
    return html
```

and then, I try to display it like this:

```
@staticmethod
def fromCollection_getPossibleLanguages(self,pageContent):
        parsedHtml = BeautifulSoup(pageContent)
        possibleMatches = parsedHtml.findAll('select',{'name':'languageid','class':'filter_select'})
        possibleMatches = possibleMatches[0].findAll('option')

        for match in possibleMatches:
            print(str(match.text.encode('unicode')) + " - " + str(match.get('value')))
```

However, all my attempts to play with .encode() function(e.g. passing a 'utf-8' or 'unicode' args)  have failed to display anything more than, for example:

```
b'\xd0\xa0\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb9' - 10
```

I'm displaying it in mac os x's terminal and in Eclipse's console view - same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to encode *at all*. BeautifulSoup has already decoded the response bytes to Unicode values, and `print()` can take care of the rest here.

However, the page *is* malformed, as there are no closing `</option>` tags. This can confuse the standard HTML parser. Install [lxml or the `html5lib` package](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser), and the page can be parsed correctly:

```
parsedHtml = BeautifulSoup(pageContent, 'lxml')
```

or

```
parsedHtml = BeautifulSoup(pageContent, 'html5lib')
```

Next, you can select the `<option>` tags with [*one* CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
possibleMatches = parsedHtml.select('select[name=languageid] option')

for match in possibleMatches:
    print(match.text, "-", match.get('value'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> possibleMatches = soup.select('select[name=languageid] option')
>>> for match in possibleMatches:
...     print(match.text, "-", match.get('value'))
... 
Language - 0
Bahasa Indonesia - 32
Català - 34
Deutsch - 4
Eesti - 41
English - 1
Español - 2
Esperanto - 22
Filipino - 21
Français - 3
Italiano - 11
Język polski - 13
LINGUA LATINA - 35
Magyar - 14
Nederlands - 7
Norsk - 18
Português - 8
Română - 27
Suomi - 20
Svenska - 17
čeština - 31
Русский - 10
देवनागरी - 39
ภาษาไทย - 38
中文 - 5
日本語 - 6
```

Comment: @martjin-pieters Thanks for the suggestion on how to fix mismatched option tags!


However, the main problem still exists. I tried doing nothing more than


    `for match in possibleMatches:
        print(match.text, "-",match.get('value'))`

And all I get is: 

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf1' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)`

So yeah, I;m kinda stuck now :/

Comment: And when I try to do:

 `print(match.text.encode('utf-8'), "-",match.get('value'))`

I still get
`b'Portugu\xc3\xaas' - 8`

Comment: Your *console or terminal* is misconfigured. Printing fails, nothing else.

Comment: Python thinks your console or terminal can only handle ASCII, and tries to encode the data accordingly. That fails. Perhaps you can write the data to a file instead, or set the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable.

Comment: @martjim-pieters Hmm, that's kinda strange, but at least, now I know what the underlying problem is (I think...) and what to google/look at to resolve it. 

Thank you so much for help! :)